# How to use mock in a private static final variable in Spock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock, spring-boot-test

Say I have a `private static final` variable in a Java class like:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    ...
}
```

Then I have test class like:

```
class MyClassTest extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  MyClass sut

  def "Testing a private static final variable"() {
    given:
    sut.LOGGER = Mock(Logger)

    when:
    ...
}
```

How can I use `Mock(Logger)` with `sut.LOGGER` where `LOGGER` is a `private static final` in `MyClass` class? Without the `final` keyword, the test would just run fine though but I wanted it to work with a `final` keyword. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Simply put: you can't. Either your class is testable (the `LOGGER` is not final) or not.

Comment: "Simply put: you can't. Either your class is testable (the LOGGER is not final) or not." - I do not believe that is correct.  Being `final` does not prevent something from being mocked.  I have posted an example.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown you might be correct about Groovy class under test. Although I think, that the OP meant rather a java class instead

Comment: @injecteer I think you are right.  That was my mistake.

Comment: @injecteer thanks for the comment. I'm kind of new to Spock. It's just that the IDE would complain that `LOGGER` should be final and there are a bunch of fields like this in the project that I'm working on.

Comment: The commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mocklog/commit/1fadffe9b9087db3e169eb3230a6ac157fd046ed converts the CUT to Java

Comment: Yes, of course you can use tools like Mockito-inline, Sarek or others in order to modify bytecode or class-loading in such a way as to allow mocking for final or static entities. But out of the box, Spock cannot do that for non-Groovy code under test. But actually, it would be better to write testable code, so we do not need dirty tricks or poer tools. Or how about configuring the log framework for the test in such a way as to use a mock logger?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, to avoid misunderstandings: I do think your solution with the Mockito inline mock maker is valid, especially because you only use `mockStatic` in order to inject a regular Spock mock and do not try to replace the whole Spock mocking system. So kudos for that. I just think that the need for using such tools is a symptom (code design smell) rather than a cure. But let us just assume that the class under test is 3rd party and we do not have the source code. 

Comment: "But out of the box, Spock cannot do that for non-Groovy code under test. " - That is correct.  i wasn't trying to suggest otherwise.  I thought the question was asking how to mock that private static variable, I didn't realize the question was asking if Spock can do it out of the box.  The answer is a simple "no". Thank you for helping to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we do not wish to use Mockito inline mock maker or other mocking power tools, but simply use Spock's on-board means, we can use another way specifically for Slf4j: use the existing logger instead of mocking it, but adding a mock appender, then verify interactions on that one. The only requirement for that is to know which actual logging tool is used or to just configure the test environment in order to use a specific one. Let us choose LogBack. If we know that Slf4J logs to LogBack, we can import its classes and cast the logger to it.

**Class under test:**

I made it a bit more complicated on purpose, so later we can test several cases for positive, negative and zero numbers:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71235231;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ClassWithLogger {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassWithLogger.class);

  public void logSomething(int i) {
    LOGGER.info("FYI, 3 * {} = {}", i, 3 * i);
    if (i < 0)
      LOGGER.warn("Be warned that {} is a negative number", i);
    if (i == 0)
      LOGGER.error("Using zero is forbidden");
  }
}
```

**Spock test**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71235231

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class ClassWithLoggerTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll("test logger with number #number")
  def "test logger"() {
    given:
    // Groovy can simply access private fields, if we know their names
    Logger logger = ClassWithLogger.LOGGER
    def appender = Mock(Appender)
    logger.addAppender(appender)

    when:
    new ClassWithLogger().logSomething(number)

    then:
    1 * appender.doAppend({ LoggingEvent event ->
      event.level == Level.INFO &&
        event.formattedMessage == "FYI, 3 * $number = ${3 * number}"
    })
    (number == 0 ? 1 : 0) * appender.doAppend({ LoggingEvent event ->
      event.level == Level.ERROR &&
        event.formattedMessage == "Using zero is forbidden"
    })
    (number < 0 ? 1 : 0) * appender.doAppend({ LoggingEvent event ->
      event.level == Level.WARN &&
        event.formattedMessage == "Be warned that $number is a negative number"
    })

    cleanup:
    logger.detachAppender(appender)

    where:
    number << [4, 1, 0, -1, -7]
  }
}
```

The dynamic interaction counts like `(number < 0 ? 1 : 0) * ...` are not super readable. I simply wanted to show off Spock's capabilities in connection with test parametrisation and cover all scenarios in a single test method. Maybe you would be better off to split it into 3 methods and cover each case separately. That way the tests would be more readable, but you would have more duplicate code, too. It is a matter of taste, I leave the choice up to you.

---

**Update:** If you prefer to calculate more of the dynamic stuff in the `where:` section (could also be done in `given:`), you can use this variation (just cosmetics, the logic is unchanged):

```java
class ClassWithLoggerTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll("test logger with number #number")
  def "test logger"() {
    given:
    // Groovy can simply access private fields, if we know their names
    Logger logger = ClassWithLogger.LOGGER
    def appender = Mock(Appender)
    logger.addAppender(appender)

    when:
    new ClassWithLogger().logSomething(number)

    then:
    infoCount * appender.doAppend({ LoggingEvent event ->
      event.level == Level.INFO && event.formattedMessage == infoMessage
    })
    errorCount * appender.doAppend({ LoggingEvent event ->
      event.level == Level.ERROR && event.formattedMessage == errorMessage
    })
    warningCount * appender.doAppend({ LoggingEvent event ->
      event.level == Level.WARN && event.formattedMessage == warningMessage
    })

    cleanup:
    logger.detachAppender(appender)

    where:
    number << [4, 1, 0, -1, -7]
    infoCount = 1
    infoMessage = "FYI, 3 * $number = ${3 * number}"
    errorCount = number == 0 ? 1 : 0
    errorMessage = "Using zero is forbidden"
    warningCount = number < 0 ? 1 : 0
    warningMessage = "Be warned that $number is a negative number"
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?gist=c233a6b198c8638f7dcc42d2f71123b0).

---

**Source:** blog post ["Don't mock static: test SLF4J Logger with appenders"](https://kotlintesting.com/mock-slf4j/), adapted to Spock.

Comment: Thanks, @kriegaex, this solution actually works. I just have to customize a little bit for my needs but the basic idea is working for me. Now the only question is if the team will adopt this approach, but that's another thing to tackle :)

Comment: The difference between my approach and the one suggested by Jeff is that his needs extra tools, but is a fully mocked unit test, while mine does not need any power tools, but does not mock the whole logging infrastructure but leaves it intact, only adding an extra appender. That can be nice if you do not mind or even want to see the original log messages on the console or in a log file. It depends on your situation, but I am always happy if I can avoid mocking static (final) stuff.